# :dependent => :destroy doesn't work on has_one relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-one, dependent-destroy

In my models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :user_detail, dependent: :destroy
end
```

and

```
class UserDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

When I call destroy for an User object, the associated UserDetail object is not being destroyed.

Here's a test (of course, it fails because `user_detail` is not nil):

```
  test "associate object should be destroyed" do
    user_id = @user.id
    @user.destroy
    user_detail = UserDetail.find_by(:user_id => user_id)
    assert_nil user_detail
  end
```

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Comment: Just do `@user.reload`... after `@user.destroy`..

Comment: If I write that right after @user.destroy it gives me one error that says it couldn't find the User with id='12'. By the way, the associated object is not being destroyed in development too. I think the problem is with the models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is fine, but it's your test code that's the problem. Try this:

```
test "associate object should be destroyed" do
  user_detail = @user.user_detail
  @user.destroy
  expect(UserDetail.find_by(:user_id => @user.id)).to be_nil
end
```

What's happening is the database row that corresponds to `user_detail` is being destroyed, but the variable still holds the value.

edit to respond to comment since I can't put the code block in the comment:

@user.id isn't nil because, if you test it, you'll see that the id is still preserved because it's the in memory model. I have a random rails app I'm testing, here's some console output:

```
irb(main):002:0> l = Loan.first
irb(main):003:0> l.destroy
irb(main):004:0> l.id
=> 14
```

Comment: I suppose that you wanted to write `UserDetail.find_by(:user_id => @user.id)`. If so, I don't understand how it is supposed to work? Shouldn't @user.id be nil?

Comment: Oh good catch, yeah, it should be `@user.id`.

But it's not nil, if you test it, you'll see that the id is still preserved because it's the in memory model. I have a random rails app I'm testing, here's some console output:

    ```irb(main):002:0> l = Loan.first
    irb(main):003:0> l.destroy
    irb(main):004:0> l.id
    => 14```